# Site aparece desconfigurado quando passa para a hospedagem

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, estou criando um site, na verdade já acabei está na fase de testes, ele estava normal quando testado localmente, porém quando eu passei ele pra hospedagem simplesmente ele desconfigurou, porém só uma parte, os sliders.

HTML dos Sliders ta assim:

```css
  .slider-holder { width: 320px; margin:0 auto; }
.slider { background-image:url(images/slider-mobile.png); padding:0 10px; width:300px;  margin:0 auto;   height: 388px;}
.slider .slide-cnt { width: 300px;  float:none; display:block; padding-top: 12px; }
.slider h4 { display:none; }
.slider h2 { font-size: 38px; text-align: center; }
.slider p { color:#cee7f1; }
.slider ul li { width: 300px; }
.slider .socials { display:none; }
.slider img { float:none; display:block; margin:0 auto; width: 194px; height: 178px; }
```

```html
<!-- slider -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="socials">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/barietoners" class="facebook-ico">facebook-ico</a>
    <a href="#" class="twitter-ico">twitter-ico</a>
    <a href="skype:diretoria@barietoner.com.br?chat" class="skype-ico">skype-ico</a>
    <a href="#" class="rss-ico">rss-ico</a>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>

  <div class="arrs">
    <a href="#" class="prev-arr"></a>
    <a href="#" class="next-arr"></a>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li id="img1">
      <div class="slide-cnt">
        <h4>Compre Online</h4>
        <h2>Seu produto em 2 cliques</h2>
        <p>Compre pela nossa loja virtual e receba seu produto sem precisar sair de casa! <a href="/loja">saiba mais</a></p>
      </div>
      <img src="css/images/mac-img.png" alt="manutencao de impressora em vinhedo" />
```

Não sei se o problema pode estar no CSS ou HTML, não faço ideia porque ele desconfigura somente essa parte.

E outra observação, a div SOCIALS simplesmente desaparece também...
O site está online, porém não sei se pode passar url por aqui, sou novo, enfim, agradeço a todos.

Comment: Ei Victor, você já conferiu no log de network do seu navegador se algum dos seus CSS ou JS estão recebendo 404? Você poderia fornecer a URL?

Comment: Mostra, onde chamas os ficheiros css no header sffv

Comment: Tem que dar uma olhada para ver se a primeira linha não tem um espaço ;)

Comment: @Rubico já olhei porém não tem nenhum erro relacionado a parte slider, tem alguns mas nada referente ao slider

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica logo após o meta

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não tem

Comment: Se for erro de Javascript, acredito que você sabe disso, mas não custa nada comentar. Após um erro de javascript, o javascript para, não continua a execução dos demais. Então se o seu slider está após esse erro, ele não será executado. Tenta passar o código do slider para antes do código problemático.

Comment: Já tentei @Rubico e nada, fiz o teste por outro navegador e a aparência fica normal, estou usando o Firefox atualizado, não sei o que pode estar acontecendo, pode mandar link por aqui? Se der eu mando para você ver

Comment: Desconheço essa regra sobre urls, a única que eu conheço é que a resposta não pode estar em uma url, pois o website pode sair do ar e com isso a resposta também. Posta ai vai. ;)

Comment: Ok @Rubico, a url é http://barietoner.com.br, já tentei muita coisa e até agora nada

Comment: Aqui está funcionando perfeitamente, não possuo o firefox (estou no serviço e não consigo instalar). Mas talvez seja um problema com o seu cache. Já sofri por horas com problema de cache. Fecha a aba do site, limpa seu cache e tenta abrir novamente.

Comment: @Rubico parece que só esta desconfigurado no Firefox, já limpei o Cache e tudo, continua assim... Mas obrigado pela ajuda e pelo tempo

Comment: @VictorGomes testei aqui no IE 11, Chrome 48 e Firefox 45 e todos parecem normal

Comment: Testou no firefox que está dando problema nos dois ambientes? O que está online e o que está local?

Comment: Obrigado @LeandroGodoyRosa, só o que está online, o offline (local) está aparecendo tudo normal, espero que seja só no meu firefox que esteja dando esse erro

Comment: Você está usando servidor Linux ?

Pode ser problema de permissão!